# Auto adjusting of UI based on screen size,UI in java swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I work on a software that runs in monitors of different screen size from laptop screens to TV screens.I would you to know about java swing feature that auto-adjust the component relatively according to screen size

Comment: This question is overly broad.

Comment: What size do you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the following code will returns the screen width and height

```
Toolkit toolkit =  Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit ();
Dimension dim = toolkit.getScreenSize();
frame.setSize(dim.width,dim.height);//here frame is your container
```

Comment: sure this gives flexibility of sizing the screen,but i am looking any feature in java that will do the resizing automatically without addin a piece of code

Answer (score 3):

You can use **ToolKit**, but its **always better to have have Half the screen Width and Height**.

```
Toolkit t = Toolkit.getDefalutToolKit();
Dimension d = t.getScreenSize();

int h = d.height;
int w = d.width;

myframe.setSize( w/2 , h/2 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Swing layouts are the thing you are looking for:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html

There are types of layouts that dynamically rearranges the components according to the application size. You can see options for layout in the link I gave above.

Fill in the components using layout and than make your application run fullscreen.

Comment: i have layoutmanagers specific to each ui and set dimensions ,but i would like like to if there a feature which would preserve the relative positioning acrosss different screen size